# Error while updating my app on play store

Tags: android

I am updating my android app on google play store, my previous app version is **2.0.0** and updated app version is *2.1.0* , but when i am updating it on play store it shows an error i.e app already have an 2 as major version why?

Comment: **versionName** is not important, you have to increase **versionCode**

Comment: Both **versionName** and **versionCode** should be updated

Comment: There is difference between `VersionName` and `VersionCode`. You might have updated `VersionName` but forgot to update `VersionCode`.

Comment: @HoseinIT, AFAIK, **versionName** does not have to be updated

Comment: yes but it's the beauty of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Update Your  **VersionCode** and **VersionName** together. To do this:

In your **Gradle Scripts** Open **>** **build.gradle(Module:app)** The file will look like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.madaris.tanzeem.tanzeemulmadaris"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Here you should change **VersionCode** too! 
Happy Coding!